# Call parent ViewModel from RecyclerView child ViewModel in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I have a View with a RecyclerView and a ViewModel, I have a list of objects, and I fill the RecyclerView with an Adapter and a ViewHolder.

Each of the objects is a ViewModel who has a click event who goes to a Detail, when the click event is fired the app asks for data to the server and if the data is correct navigates to the detail screen.

I have a "loading" check to prevent the user to press two times the same child, but as every child has his own instance of the viewmodel, if you press fast different buttons (fast than the server response) all of them are fired.

So, is there anyway to call the parent viewmodel of a RecyclerView viewmodel child, or any other option? Actually I can just think on make a singleton to keep the childs loading status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end what I used was a singleton with and AtomicBoolean like this:

```
public final class LoadingStatusSingleton {
    private static final LoadingStatusSingleton ourInstance = new LoadingStatusSingleton();

    public static LoadingStatusSingleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private LoadingStatusSingleton() {
        isLoading = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }

    private AtomicBoolean isLoading;

    public synchronized boolean getLoading() {
        return isLoading.get();
    }

    public synchronized void setLoading(boolean value) {
        isLoading.set(value);
    }
}
```

And I change the AtomicBoolean to true or false on demand from the different viewmodels instances.

Answer (score 0):

add a boolean property in your viewmodel, smt like : `isLoading`, and set it to `true`when you calling webservice, and while `isLoading == true` disable click event from view child.

Comment: that's what I first do, but this only prevents the recall from one single child to itself, if you press one and then press another, the viewmodel bolean of the second one is on false.

Comment: did you set Tag to your viewholder yet?

Comment: Mm... no I don't think so

Comment: I'd add isLoading to data model instead, and keep only one item isloading